# ignoring text height using float left doesn't work but right does

Tags: css, html

i want to make a box-model using html and css .so i made a nested divs and use top left to position correctly .it works .
here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9kL3zoxe/) preview .

[image]

but when i added a text to divs the vertical  alignments get changed which is not what i want.however text positioned correctly at left side as i want.

[image]

as my experience i gave float value so div should ignore span tags height.it works when i use `float:right` but not `float:left` .as you can see when i use right text is correctly positioned at right but why not with left?

[image]

i want to text align at left side.why it act like this ?and how can i position text left without affecting relative divs

html code

```
  <div class="squ">
    <div id="sone" class="margina">
    <span class="boxtext">margin</span>
        <div id="stwo" class="margina">
           <span class="boxtext">border</span>
            <div id="sthree" class="margina">
              <span class="boxtext">padding</span>
                <div id="sfour" class="margina">
                   <span class="boxtext">elem</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css for span text

```
.boxtext{
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

Comment: can you show the full css

Comment: @sebastianbrosch here is jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9kL3zoxe/ you can see full css there

Comment: use box-sizing: border-box;  concept, it will solve your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because your `.margina` is `position:relative;` Although you are specifying the `top` & `left` position, the elements are still being positioned relatively which is giving a stepping effect.
I've changed it to `absolute` and it works fine:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9kL3zoxe/9/)

```
.margina{
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:30px;
}
```

For completeness sake, this is how the browser is actually rendering the page before doing the `top` & `left` positioning on the relative `.margina` divs. I've added `overflow:hidden` to them to demonstrate:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9kL3zoxe/11/)

```
.margina{
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
    left:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either give the classes margina or textbox a position of absolute. what you did was not working for you because floats are generally positioned relative and it is clashing with the parent element. The reason why the float:right works is because positioning is not needed for it.